# Cannot recognize strange json-like data structure

Tags: json

Can someone identify what this data format is?

```
 a:6:{s:4:"site";a:11:{s:13:"CardNumber";s:2:"95";s:14:"ContNumber";s:9:"018188649";s:11:"SiteRef";s:16:"US015";
...
```

It is not modern, it has been in use for at least 10 years.

Comment: seems to be separated by type:length:content

Comment: Have you posted the whole data string ? (or you have posted just part of it ?)

Comment: Yes, it is php serialization, thank you @sp00m